RevenueCat REST API not working with Stripe public API key
In my Flutter project, I managed to add a paywall thanks to RevenueCat, for Android, iOS and macOS.
Now, I want to achieve the same for Windows and Linux. Unfortunately, the purchases_flutter package is not available for Windows or Linux.
So I choose to create a simple payment link using Stripe, and connect Stripe to RevenueCat. Then I can interact with RevenueCat from the Windows and Linux versions of my app using the RevenueCat REST API.
Here are the tasks I need to achieve:

list my offerings
check if a user has purchased my one-time payment product or not
recover a one-time payment purchase

And here is my problem:

if I try to achieve the tasks listed above only using my Stripe public API key (with Postman, for example), by following the documentation, I got an error telling me that my key is invalid.
if I do the exact same thing, but with a secret key I created with the right authrorizations, it works.

And that’s really annoying for me, since I don’t want to deal with a back-end just to store a private key. Also, I don't understand why I need to deal with a private key in that use case, where only a public API key is needed for the purchases_flutter package to work.
Is there a way then to achieve the tasks above only using the Stripe public API key? Or is it save to use a secret key only dedicated to the tasks above with the minimum authorizations that I can store in my app?
Thanks for your help
